# Missing SSD drive

Tags: partitioning, ssd

When I installed ubuntu I gave permission for the ubuntu installer to automatically partition my storage. I am now unable to locate my SSD drive.

Here is information about my partitions:

```
sudo lsblk
NAME                    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                       8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─sda1                    8:1    0   487M  0 part  /boot
└─sda5                    8:5    0   931G  0 part  
  └─sda5_crypt          252:0    0   931G  0 crypt 
    ├─ubuntu--vg-root   252:1    0 923.2G  0 lvm   /
    └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 252:2    0   7.9G  0 lvm   
      └─cryptswap1      252:3    0   7.9G  0 crypt [SWAP]
sr0                      11:0    1  1024M  0 rom   
loop0                     7:0    0     2M  0 loop  /mnt


sudo blkid
/dev/mapper/sda5_crypt: UUID="mVyPmV-H30I-Rycb-0N66-gSAC-otYD-X3TnAu" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UUID="b81a1102-4d14-4061-882b-64cc86c1ed90" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda1: UUID="a9b83004-28a5-4e03-9cf0-5fda39d74ae4" TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="42700d9b-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="960539f6-57d1-46b4-9486-db9c4bdfcc5c" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="42700d9b-05"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: UUID="35bf39cb-d01c-4662-b7ed-43214cb68bf0" TYPE="swap"
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1: UUID="f1d2859e-4c2a-4f04-86a7-f7face7408a5" TYPE="swap"
/dev/loop0: UUID="7FE1-D94A" TYPE="vfat"

sudo lshw -businfo | grep '^scsi'
scsi@0:0.0.0      /dev/sda    disk           1TB ST1000LM024 HN-M
scsi@0:0.0.0,1    /dev/sda1   volume         487MiB Linux filesystem partition
scsi@0:0.0.0,2                volume         931GiB Extended partition
scsi@2:0.0.0      /dev/cdrom  disk           DVD-RAM UJ8D1
```

And what I believe to be the SSD device listed:

```
sudo lshw -C storage
  *-storage               
       description: SATA controller
       product: 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
       version: 04
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
       resources: irq:27 ioport:4088(size=8) ioport:4094(size=4) ioport:4080(size=8) ioport:4090(size=4) ioport:4060(size=32) memory:f3b17000-f3b177ff
  *-scsi:0
       physical id: 1
       logical name: scsi0
       capabilities: emulated
  *-scsi:1
       physical id: 2
       logical name: scsi2
       capabilities: emulated
```

Please let me know if any further output is needed!

**Bonus:** on a possibly unrelated note - points for anybody that can help figure out this issue below :)
[image]